# Subdomains for 1 IP but multiple webservers

Tags: routes, webserver, subdomain, ipv4

The traditional way to host multiple websites on a single IP was to use a shared host and use an Apache virtualhost config for each site. Thus different domain names mapped to the  different sites based on a virtualhost lookup but they all went to the same IP. However I would like to know:

**Is possible to have multiple webservers on a private LAN that can all be accessed on port 80 through a single public facing router/dns/whatever which uses a single public IP.**

Ideally the different servers would be accessed by subdomains, such as server1.my-site.com and server2.my-site.com. This is fairly easy to do if your webservers are allowed to serve websites on different ports with port-forwarding, but I need the outside world to not have to know what port to connect on and be able to just input server1.my-domain.com into their browser instead of server1.my-domain.com:1234

This is only an issue due to the increasing scarcity of IPv4 addresses and IPv6 isn't "ready" yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is. You have to setup the router as a **reverse proxy** and forward HTTP requests to one of the hosts in the private network based on the `Host` header or the request URL. [Nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/Main) is a popular choice when it comes to reverse proxying.

If you want to proxy services other than HTTP, SMTP or IMAP servers, then you need to use iptables instead, such as

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d $DOMAIN_NAME -j DNAT --to-destination $SERVER2_IP
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: Thank you. I take it that Nginx can proxy all TCP port types so this doesn't just apply to webservers? E.g. could I use such a system to run several minecraft servers?

Comment: No, Nginx only handles HTTP, SMTP and IMAP. I don't know what protocol Minecraft adopts, but if it is based on raw TCP, then you should use `iptables` and setup a forward rule.

Comment: ah so I want something like this: 
`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d $DOMAIN_NAME -j DNAT --to-destination $SERVER2_IP` [next line] 
`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE`
(however this will prevent secondary host from being able to use vhosts)

Comment: Yes. About vhosts, I suppose Minecraft has no concept of vhosts, so you should be ok. About HTTP, Nginx will preserve the URL and Host header, so vhosts should work fine.

Comment: Apologies, I meant that if I used the generic iptables solution to resolve both webservers and minecraft servers, then vhosts would not work. However, vhosts would work if I used nginx as a reverse proxy but would only work with proxying webservers correct?

Comment: @Programster: -d will resolve the $DOMAIN_NAME on the proxy side (once, before submitting the address to the kernel, to quote the manpage). Think about it, how does the proxy know which hostname the client used to retrieve the shared IP? The client has to send it along somehow, which is what the HTTP Host header is for. Many protocols provide such info (TLS has SNI for example) and they usually feature it under the `vhost` umbrella term. However, some protocols don't (I suspect Minecraft doesn't, could be wrong). When they do, you'll never get away with just iptables, it's always specific.

Answer (score 0):

Stefano's solution works only if it is possible to install Nginx on the router. If that is not possible setup reverse proxy (Nginx/Squid/Apache etc.) on a server behind the router. Port forward the traffic from router to the reverse proxy server. Setup reverse proxy to forward the traffic to different servers in the network.

Comment: Thank you for this. Yes, if I was setting this up at home, that is what I would need to do.